# Git: reset deleted file from index

Tags: git, git-reset, git-index

1. Create 2 files: `one.txt` and `two.txt`.
2. Commit both files: `git add -A` and `git commit -m "message"`
3. Edit `one.txt` and add it to index: `git add one.txt`
4. Delete `two.txt` and add it to index: `git rm two.txt`

I want to commit only `one.txt`, therefore I need to reset `two.txt` from index.
**How to do it?**

`git commit one.txt` works, but it is not applicable, because may be 100 files instead `one.txt`.

Comment: This is covered in the excellent Pro Git book: [2.4 Git Basics - Undoing Things](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things)

Answer (score -1):

Command `git reset HEAD two.txt` reset the file in index and don't touch it in working directory. What you need!